# Flutter Firebase try catch does not fire

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

When using firebase auth and type not registered email,
although I used try - catch, that does not fire. 
`fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` definitely throw PlatformException but that code does not catch that. 
I suffered this problem about 2days..... please help me

[image]

```
Future<bool> signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      var result = await fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      if (result != null) {
        setUser(result.user);
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("User").doc(_user.uid).get().then((doc) {
          info.set(
              name: doc["name"],
              email: doc["email"],
              phoneNumber: doc["phoneNumber"],
              follower: doc["follower"],
              following: doc["following"],
              like: doc["like"],
              review: doc["review"],
              visited: doc["visited"],
              favorite: doc["favorite"],
            );
            print(doc['name']);
            notifyListeners();
        });
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      List<String> result = e.toString().split(", ");
      setLastFBMessage(result[1]);
      return false;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      List<String> result = e.toString().split(", ");
      setLastFBMessage(result[1]);
      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      List<String> result = e.toString().split(", ");
      setLastFBMessage(result[1]);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: had a luck running the project in android studio ?

Comment: Thx for comment. I just found that vscode jus tdown when Exception occured... My laptop hate android studio but i think i should use that... thx